# How to call multiple distribution functions from different vectors into a function in R

Tags: r, list, function, apply, distribution

Lets talk you through my workflow:

**General idea**

Based on data in a dataframe, select the appropriate distribution functions, combine them in all possible ways to get the mean of the combined distributions.

**Starting position**

- I have a large data frame `df`. In there I have different variables `var1`, `var2` and `var3` in this example which contains data to select the appropriate distribution function.
- I have several distribution functions per variable:

```
var1_distr1 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 3, sd = 1))
var1_distr2 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 6, sd = 1))
var1_distr3 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 2, sd = 2))

var2_distr1 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 5, sd = 3))
var2_distr2 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 3, sd = 1))
var2_distr3 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 4, sd = 2))

var3_distr1 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 4, sd = 1))
var3_distr2 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 5, sd = 1))
var3_distr3 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 7, sd = 2))
```

**Select the right distribution**

Using an `if_else` on each of the `var`s I generate the appropriate distribution per case in a new vector. The `if_else` looks like this for `var1` and has the same appearance for all `var`s:

```
df$distr_var1 <- if_else(df$info < 0, "var1_distr1",
                         if_else(df$info > 0 & df$info < 100, "var1_distr2", "var1_distr3")
```

This results in the following `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(distr_var1 = c("var1_distr1", "var1_distr3", "var1_distr1", "var1_distr2", "var1_distr2", "var1_distr1", "var1_distr3"),
                 distr_var2 = c("var2_distr2", "var2_distr1", "var2_distr2", "var2_distr1", "var2_distr3", "var2_distr3", "var2_distr1"),
                 distr_var3 = c("var3_distr2", "var3_distr3", "var3_distr1", "var3_distr1", "var3_distr2", "var3_distr3", "var3_distr1"))
```

**Combine distribution functions**

To combine distribution functions in a new proportional distribution function I have created this function based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73362544/in-r-pass-multiple-distribution-functions-in-a-list-to-a-new-function):

```
foo <- function(...){
  #set x values
  x <- seq(1, 10, by = 1)
  #create y values
  y <- 1L
  for (fun in list(...)) y <- y * fun(x)
  #create new PDF
  p <- data.frame(x,y)
  pdqr::new_d(p, type = "continuous")
}
```

And I have stored the PDFs in a list:

```
PDFS <- list(var1_distr1 = var1_distr1, var1_distr2 = var1_distr2, var1_distr3 = var1_distr3,
             var2_distr1 = var2_distr1, var2_distr2 = var2_distr2, var2_distr3 = var2_distr3,
             var3_distr1 = var3_distr1, var3_distr2 = var3_distr2, var3_distr3 = var3_distr3)
```

I would like to use the function `foo` in the `df` to generate proportional distributions for all combinations of distributions given in the `df`. So, for each case, a the following combinations: `var1_var2`, `var1_var3`, `var2_var3`, `var1_var2_var3`.

**Calculate mean over distributions**

If I want to calculate a mean over the distributions individually, I can do this:

```
means <- sapply(PDFS, pdqr::summ_mean)
df$mean_var1 <- means[df$distr_var1]
```

Or:

```
df$mean_var2 <- sapply(mget(df$distr_var2), pdqr::summ_mean)
```

Both approaches work fine. But on the combinations `var1_var2`, `var1_var3`, `var2_var3`, `var1_var2_var3` I have not found a suitable approach, but tried these:

```
df$var1_var2_mean <- sapply(foo(mget(mapply(PDFS, sapply, df$distr_var1, df$distr_var2))), pdqr::summ_mean)
```

I tried to overcome not calling functions by using a list, but things seem to get too complicated / nested to work nicely...

*Question*

How to select the appropriate distributions given in `distr_var1`, `distr_var2` and `distr_var3`, combined them using `foo` and calculate the mean using `pdqr::summ_mean`?

I'm happy with all comments, also on the workflow in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `foreach` loop works for me:

```
df$var1_var2_mean <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(df), .combine = c) %do% {
  A <- as.name(df$var1[i])
  B <- as.name(df$var2[i])
  mean <- summ_mean(foo(get(A),get(B)))
}
```

And, for each combination I need to do this. At least I got it working...